# higher algebraic homotopy groups for schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I think I understand how to define the algebraic fundamental group  $\pi^{alg}_{1}(X)$ of a scheme and I think I understand the relation between $\pi^{alg}_{1}(X)$ and $\pi_{1}(X(\mathbb{C}))$, where $X$ is a nice algebraic variety over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it reasonable to hope for a definition of higher algebraic homotopy groups $\pi_{n}^{alg}(X)$ of a scheme $X$ ?

Comment: There are higher algebraic homotopy groups of schemes.  This was first developed by Artin-Mazur, and then developed further by Eric Friedlander.  Recently, Michael McQuillan has proposed a different definition of the second homotopy group.

Comment: @JasonStarr does it recover the relation between $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{1}^{alg}$ ? Could you put the references ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_homotopy_type

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/étale+homotopy

Answer (score 7):

I am writing the comments above so that this question does not remain unanswered.  As Qiaochu Yuan writes, one good resource is the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_homotopy_type) for etale homotopy theory.  Here are two references from MathSciNet.

MR0883959 (88a:14024) 
Artin, M.; Mazur, B. 
Etale homotopy. 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 100. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1986. iv+169 pp. 
 
ISBN: 3-540-04619-4

MR0676809 (84h:55012) 
Friedlander, Eric M. 
Étale homotopy of simplicial schemes. 
Annals of Mathematics Studies, 104. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J.; 
 
University of Tokyo Press, Tokyo, 1982. vii+190 pp. 
ISBN: 0-691-08288-X; 0-691-08317-7

Here is the URL for the article of Michael McQuillan: [Elementary Topology of Champs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00797).